# Combine two array into one while getting the sum of instances in second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays. The first array is this:

```
arrayOne = [
{id: 1, type: 'Animal', legs: 4},
{id: 2, type: 'Animal', legs: 2},
{id: 3, type: 'Animal', legs: 8},
{id: 4, type: 'Plant', legs: 0},
]
```

This is the second array:

```
arrayTwo = [
{typeId: 1, processing: 2},
{typeId: 1, processing: 3},
{typeId: 1, approved: 3},
{typeId: 1, approved: 2},
{typeId: 1, disapproved: 3},
{typeId: 1, disapproved: 2},
{typeId: 2, approved: 2},
{typeId: 2, disapproved: 1},
{typeId: 2, disapproved: 1},
{typeId: 3, approved: 2},
{typeId: 4, disapproved: 3},
]
```

If id of arrayOne is equal to typeId of arrayTwo, then append arrayTwo into arrayOne and sum up the number of processing, approved and disapproved. This is my desiredArray:

```
desiredArray = [
{id: 1, type: 'Animal', legs: 4, processing: 5, approved: 5, disapproved: 5},
{id: 2, type: 'Animal', legs: 2, approved: 2, disapproved: 2},
{id: 3, type: 'Animal', legs: 8, approved: 2},
{id: 4, type: 'Plant', legs: 0, disapproved: 3},
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific question about how to do this? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question with more details and _your current code attempting this_.

Comment: this is not the purpose of this site. We are happy to answer questions - not complete your assignment for you. Give this a try, come back with some code that doesn't work and we'll help you out. (or just ignore this, because invariably someone will come along and do your work for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `reduce` the second array and then `map` it to the first one:

```js
const arrayOne = [{id: 1, type: 'Animal', legs: 4},{id: 2, type: 'Animal', legs: 2},{id: 3, type: 'Animal', legs: 8},{id: 4, type: 'Plant', legs: 0},];
const arrayTwo = [{typeId: 1, processing: 2},{typeId: 1, processing: 3},{typeId: 1, approved: 3},{typeId: 1, approved: 2},{typeId: 1, disapproved: 3},{typeId: 1, disapproved: 2},{typeId: 2, approved: 2},{typeId: 2, disapproved: 1},{typeId: 2, disapproved: 1},{typeId: 3, approved: 2},{typeId: 4, disapproved: 3},];

const reduced = arrayTwo.reduce((a,{typeId, ...rest})=>{
    a[typeId] ??= {};
    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k,v])=>{
        a[typeId][k] ??= 0;
        a[typeId][k]+=v;
    });
    return a;
},{});

const result = arrayOne.map(o=>({...o, ...reduced[o.id]}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Let me code it for u.

```js
arrayOne = [{
    id: 1,
    type: 'Animal',
    legs: 4
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'Animal',
    legs: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    type: 'Animal',
    legs: 8
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    type: 'Plant',
    legs: 0
  },
]

arrayTwo = [{
    typeId: 1,
    processing: 2
  },
  {
    typeId: 1,
    processing: 3
  },
  {
    typeId: 1,
    approved: 3
  },
  {
    typeId: 1,
    approved: 2
  },
  {
    typeId: 1,
    disapproved: 3
  },
  {
    typeId: 1,
    disapproved: 2
  },
  {
    typeId: 2,
    approved: 2
  },
  {
    typeId: 2,
    disapproved: 1
  },
  {
    typeId: 2,
    disapproved: 1
  },
  {
    typeId: 3,
    approved: 2
  },
  {
    typeId: 4,
    disapproved: 3
  },
]



for (let x in arrayOne) {
  for (let y of arrayTwo) {
    if(arrayOne[x].id == y.typeId){
        arrayOne[x] = {...arrayOne[x], ...y};
    }
  }
}

console.log(arrayOne)
```

Comment: This doesn't sum the values, it just overwrites them with the last seen value for each property.